# RowLimit - The allowed range of values is 0 to 500

Tags: 2013, search, keywordquery

I have a KQL query used with KeywordQuery that used to work in SP 2010 but no longer works in 2013:

```
scope="All Sites" AND path:"/sites/" AND path:"/Pages/ThisPage.aspx"
```

The error that’s given is:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
The allowed range of values is 0 to 500    Parameter name: RowLimit
  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryProperties.ValidateRowLimit(Int32 value)
  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryProperties.set_RowLimit(Int32 value)
```

I need to set RowLimit to 1000, but I don’t know why there is a limit of 500. Decompiling the code for Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryProperties, RowLimit is compared against a property called MaxRowLimit which defaults to 10000, so I suppose  that value is being set by some other means (I'm not modifying the value from the default)

My decompiler suggests that MaxRowLimit is set in a few ways:

- this.MaxRowLimit = cachedSearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxRowLimit;
- this.MaxRowLimit = cachedSearchServiceApplicationInfo.DiscoveryMaxRowLimit;
- By setting the Query property
- During internal cloning

I've checked the service application but can't see a way to set a max row limit for that application.

Is this a search service application configuration issue?

Update:
I followed [this blog post](http://www.sharepointfront.com/paged-custom-search-query-using-keywordquery/) to check the Max setting using powershell and the result was 10000:

```
PS> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
PS> $ssa.GetSetting('Config:qp_MaxResultsReturned')
10000
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decompiling the SearchServiceApplication we see that MaxRowLimit on that application defaults to 500 and that value is passed to the query.

The SearchServiceApplication MaxRowLimit can be modified as follows:

```
PS> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
PS> $ssa.MaxRowLimit = 1000
PS> $ssa.Update()
PS> iisreset
```

Comment: So did this work for you?

Comment: Yes it solved the problem

Comment: I avoided an iisreset by restarting the Search service

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying in such an old thread, but I just ran into this.

It seems that the list search box in SharePoint Server 2016 (and newer as well, I assume) is also restricted by the [MaxRowLimit setting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208462/sharepoint-search-js-returns-only-500-search-results) for Search Service Applications. It doesn't seem to matter if the list view has an object limit which gives you paging, you can't get more than 500 results. It's not the same as paging built into the search query itself, I assume.

It's weird that I ran into it now after so many years, but I suppose it's more common for users to just use metadata filtering instead of list search.